# Sharing a code fragment all over the website

Tags: php, html

So, if I have a website containing two or more webpages with some same code fragment (e.g. side menu or top bar), how can I store this fragment in one place for using by all the webpages on the website?

I tried to put that repeating code to separate php file, like:

```
<?php echo "<div id='menu'> ... </div>";
```

and then just use

```
<?php include "menu.php" ?>
```

but problems occur with double-quotes inside double-quotes (considering I have PHP and JS scripts inside that "central" one, it's even more trouble), interpretation and so on.

What should I use (preferable HTML and PHP tools) to achieve that "code sync"?

Comment: "but problems occur with double-quotes inside double-quotes" wut? why?

Comment: Escape double quotes by using the magic backslash: `echo "\"";` will do what you need. Look up [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)...

Comment: Some basic php syntax research is required

Comment: Double quotes inside double quotes will need to be escaped with a \ and single quotes inside single quotes will need the same treatment, that's it

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ OFF(the code markup and a single backslash doesn't play well with markdown, I've been having troubles with it too..)

Comment: Well, if I need, for example, JS-based visitors counter on every page, I put `<script>blah "blah" "blah" blah</script>` to php file so there it looks like `echo "<script>blah \"blah\" \"blah\" blah</script>"` which is really uncomfortable to view and/or edit with those `\` things.

Comment: you know you can just `include 'menu.html'` or `include 'menu.php'` without echo just using html tags

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ I know about that escaping. It's quite inconvenient to use those `\` with lots of `"`.

Comment: @nomicos When writing any programing language's code: Adhering to syntax for language has precedence over comfort for the reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why are you echoing HTML?

**How can I put double-quotes inside double-quotes?**

You can escape the double-quote by prepending a backslash:

```
echo "<div id=\"some-id\">";
```

**But, you're dealing with the wrong problem!**

You're going along the right lines with re-using code, but you don't need to `echo` HTML. Any HTML outside of PHP tags will parse as regular HTML anyway, so just do it like this:

```
<div id='menu'>
    ...
</div>
```

Then `require_once('menu.php');` to import the file. This way, you won't have to mess around with escaping nested quotes.

**What if I have dynamic content in my menu?**

Good question, then use something like this:

```
<div id='menu'>
<?php foreach($menuitems as $menuitem): ?>
    <div id='<?php echo $menuitem['id']; ?>'>
        <?php echo $menuitem['text']; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

By keeping the PHP and the HTML in separate tags, you create code which is easy to parse, easy to read and easy to maintain.

**Similarly, don't use inline JavaScript**

Keep your js in separate files, and call it from within your HTML like this:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You know you can just `include 'menu.html'` or `include 'menu.php'` without echo just using html tags and adding any php functionality inline like you would normally.